# how to show daterangepicker by default onload in jquery without using bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to show calendar by default on load. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

```
<li class="contact-us__input-box-type">
                  <a data-open="datetimepicker" class="datetimepickerInitialze">10 Apr 2022 - 10 May 2022</a>
               </li>
  <div class="reveal generic_modal ap-modal look-up__modal mobile-height look-up__modal--siteReport" id="datetimepicker" data-options="closeOnClick:false;closeOnEsc:false;" data-reveal>
               <div class="ap-modal__header border-bottom">
                 
               </div>
               <div class="ap-modal__body ap-modal__body--reserve text-center">
                  <form id="contact-form" setAttribute="addForm">
                     <div class="ap-tabs" data-simplebar>
                        <div class="ap-tabs__content">
                           <div class="ap-tabs__content-block details-tab">
                              <div class="ap-form">
                                 <div class="form-group__list ap-form__row text-left">
                                       <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x cell">
                                        
                                          <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 range-setting">
                                            
                                             <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                                                <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 cell pl0" id="stuff">
                                                   <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
                                                </div>
                                               
                                             </div>
                                             
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
              </div>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left'
      }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$('input[name="daterange"]').focus()` should auto-show the datepicker.   Or have it as the first input on your page so it's focus'd by default.

Comment: No I tried but didn't work calendar should show by default in modal

Comment: Do you have other inputs with the same name?  Do you call .focus() *after* the modal has been displayed?  Works fine without a modal: https://jsfiddle.net/ajewztn8/   Please update your snippet to include your actual code (including the modal).

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m Thanks for your quick reply I have modified my code In modal not able to print by default